# form.get_user() returning None in Django

Tags: python, django, view, model

Why does `form.get_user()` within the `if form.is_valid()` statement return a value whereas `form.get_user()` outside of the statement returns `None`

Values passed to form: `{username='sheriffcarlos', password='Iamc@tbug'}`

Example 1:

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
from django.contrib.auth import login
import logging

def user_login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AuthenticationForm(request, request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.get_user()
            logger.info(user) #Logs Sheriffcarlos
        else:
            #Do Something Else
    #Do Something
```

Example 2:

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
from django.contrib.auth import login
import logging

def user_login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AuthenticationForm(request, request.POST)
        user = form.get_user()
        logger.info(user) #Logs None

        if form.is_valid():
            #Do something
        else:
            #Do Something Else
    #Do Something
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the `get_user()` method only returns the `user_cache`. Indeed, in the [source code [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.2.x/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L227-L228), we see:

> ```
> def get_user(self):
>      return self.user_cache
> ```

The `user_cache` is set to `None` in the constructor, and populated with the user, if the credentials match in the `clean` method:

> ```
>     def clean(self):
>         username = self.cleaned_data.get('username')
>         password = self.cleaned_data.get('password')
>
>         if username is not None and password:
>             self.user_cache = authenticate(self.request, username=username, password=password)
>             if self.user_cache is None:
>                 raise self.get_invalid_login_error()
>             else:
>                 self.confirm_login_allowed(self.user_cache)
>
>         return self.cleaned_data
> ```

This `clean()` method is triggered when you can `.is_valid()`, since then the form will first validate the fields, and then clean the fields, and eventually clean the entire object. Indeed, if we look at the [source code of the `Form` class [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.2.x/django/forms/forms.py#L166-L175), we see:

> ```
> @property
> def errors(self):
>     """Return an ErrorDict for the data provided for the form."""
>     if self._errors is None:
>         self.full_clean()
>     return self._errors
>
> def is_valid(self):
>     """Return True if the form has no errors, or False otherwise."""
>     return self.is_bound and not self.errors
> ```

The `.is_valid()` method thus will obtain the `.errors` property, and this will trigger a `full_clean()` that will populate the `user_cache`.

It is also sensical to first *validate* a form, and only when the *form* is valid provide a user.